# Momentjs - date not manipulatable

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I am trying to subtract 5 minutes from a custom moment date time but it does not modify the date. The code for the custom moment datetime is as follows;

```
myDateString = '2016-05-05 16:06:00';

myStartDate = moment(myDateString, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').subtract(5, 'm');

// returns 2016-05-05 16:06:00
```

Whereas, if I just modify a non-custom moment, e.g. `moment()` it does work

```
myStartDate = moment().subtract(5, 'm');

// returns 2016-05-05 16:01:00 (assuming it's currently 16:06)
```

How do I modify a customised moment date?

Comment: Based on your example output, it looks like the opposite.  The non-altered moment is subtracting.

Comment: I've reworded the question so it makes a little more sense. I'm trying to modify a custom moment datetime, which is currently not working.

Comment: Works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/dcyemcec/ (Are you sure you didnt output the `myDateString` by accident?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output the results of the calculation as a string you need to add .format, for example:

```
myDateString = '2016-05-05 16:06:00';
myNewString = moment(myDateString).subtract(5, 'm').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Alternatively you may wish to keep the new moment object:

```
myDateString = '2016-05-05 16:06:00';
myMomentObject = moment(myDateString).subtract(5, 'm');
```

And output the value it holds later with, for example:

```
myMomentObject.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```